# Why are the statements after if statement not running as expected in a synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have a simple class with two synchronized methods. One which should withdraw cash and one which should deposit cash.

And then I have another main class with an inner class. Both the main class and the inner class are implementing Runnable, where the main class is running the "withdraw"-method and the inner class running the "deposit"-method.

When that is done I am creating two Threads to run (i.e. start) the separate methods in the separate "Runnable"-classes.

The class with the synchronized methods have these methods:

```
package test;

public class ThreadClass {


int amount = 10;


synchronized void withdraw(int amount) {
    System.out.println("going to withdraw...");

    if(this.amount < amount) {
        System.out.println("Less balance..");
        try {
            wait();

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    this.amount+=amount;
    System.out.println("withdrawal completed");
}


synchronized void deposit(int amount) {
    System.out.println("going to deposit...");
    this.amount+=amount;
    System.out.println("deposit completed");
    notify();       
 }
}
```

and the class which is responsible for implementing Runnable and also running the example application looks like this:

```
package test;

public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    ThreadClass withDraw = new ThreadClass();
    withDraw.withdraw(20);


}



class Threadtest2 implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    ThreadClass t10 = new ThreadClass();
    t10.deposit(60);

 }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ThreadTest tester = new ThreadTest();
    ThreadTest.Threadtest2 tester2 = tester.new Threadtest2();


    Thread t1 = new Thread(tester);
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(tester2);
    t2.start();





 }

}
```

So when I run this program I am expecting that the notify()-call in the deposit method should notify the withdraw()-method so that the last lines also get executed, i.e.

```
    this.amount+=amount;
    System.out.println("withdrawal completed");
```

..but the application is keeping running and never get to that line so I have to manually terminate it. Is this not the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

The `synchronized` methods are synchronized on the current instance of the object. So `wait()` and `notify()` should be called on the exact same object. But you create two different instances of the `ThreadClass` object, so you call `wait()` and `notify()` on different objects.

You should create a single instance of `ThreadClass` and pass it to the threads, e.g. via a constructor:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private ThreadClass account;

    public ThreadTest(ThreadClass account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        account.withdraw(20);
    }

}

class Threadtest2 implements Runnable{

    private ThreadClass account;

    public Threadtest2(ThreadClass account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        account.deposit(60);
    }

}
```

And then initialize them like so:

```
ThreadClass account = new ThreadClass();

ThreadTest tester = new ThreadTest(account);
ThreadTest.Threadtest2 tester2 = tester.new Threadtest2(account);
```

Also note that after `wait()` the condition `this.amount < amount` could still be true, if the deposit amount was insufficient. So you should check the amount and call `wait()` in cycle, until this condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot. This thing with Concurrency is pretty new to me although I have been working with Java for some time now. But I guess its a topic you really need to invest a lot of time for in order to be really able to grasp it. 

I assume by **cycle** you mean implementing a while-loop in order to prevent a spurious wake up from the Thread scheduler?

Comment: Yes, and even if the thread is notified by a `notify()` call, the condition could still not be satisfied. Imagine you have 0 on your account, then you call `withdraw(100)`, then `deposit(50)`. The deposit value is still not enough to cover the withdrawal.

Comment: @ErfanTavoosi, `wait()` and `notify()` are meant to be used in a very specific way. Oracle's "[Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)" tutorial does a good job of explaining how and why.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thank you. I usually don't follow Oracle but I assume they go through things very carefully. So I should probably read it.